# Any one has an idea how to make this in CSS so it is responsive?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm wondering how to achieve this in CSS (and less and jquery is also good :)

I have the slider, but it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image: a slider]

The fonts is of curse no problem, not making the stuff round and so on, removing border and stuff...

I'm wondering how I can achieve this little pins: [image] in CSS, so it keeps the right dimensions, and squeezes together when the screen-size is different. By the way, thanks a bunch to danielcrisp, [for this awesome slider for AngularJS.](https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Came up with this solution
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bkdAs

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
  width:500px;
  height:20px;
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
.slider .pin{
  height:100%;
  width:10%;
  float:left;
  border-right:2px solid red;
  transform: translateY(55%);
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.slider .pin:last-child{
  display:none;
}
```

Might be easier to achieve using some javascript though for appending the divs inside the slider

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to make 8 elements with position absolute and left 10*n%.
It may be possible to use css pseudo element instead of DOM elements to prevent bloating your HTML.

Edit: it turns out you can't chain css pseudo-elements, you'll have to append real DOM elements to your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/0hea6ody/

```
<span class="grad grad1"></span>
...
<span class="grad grad9"></span>
```